How to add HTML block after/before my table in Filament Resource Page
As a beginner with no experience in Filament, how can I display additional text or information alongside my table after it's created? I'm looking to add contextual details or guidance for users interacting with the table. Any help would be appreciated!

If you want to add additional HTML on resource page, you can use render hook.
For example, if you want to add content on list page, you can add this boot function to the ListPageResource
use Filament\View\PanelsRenderHook;
use Filament\Support\Facades\FilamentView;

public function boot(): void
    {
        FilamentView::registerRenderHook(PanelsRenderHook::RESOURCE_PAGES_LIST_RECORDS_TABLE_BEFORE, fn () => <<<HTML
            <div>
                Hello World
            </div>
        HTML);
    }

If you want to add that render hook to every resource page, you can use renderHook on the panel provider
return $panel
          ->renderHook(PanelsRenderHook::RESOURCE_PAGES_LIST_RECORDS_TABLE_BEFORE, fn () => <<<HTML
            <div>
                Hello World
            </div>
        HTML)

Reference: Filament Render hooks
